# .Net - DataAnnotations - Validate 2 dependent DateTime

Tags: c#, validation, .net-3.5, data-annotations

Let say I got the following classes:

```
public class Post 
{
    public Date BeginDate { get; set; }

    [Validate2Date(BeginDate, EndDate, ErrorMessage = "End date have to occurs after Begin Date")]
    public Date EndDate { get; set; }
}

public class Validate2Dates : ValidationAttribute
{
    public Validate2Dates(DateTime a, DateTime b)
    { ... }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        // Compare date and return false if b < a
    }
}
```

My problem is how to use my custom Validate2Dates attribute because I can't  do that:

```
[Validate2Date(BeginDate, EndDate, ErrorMessage = "End date have to occurs before Begin Date")]
```

I got the following error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property '...Post.BeginDate.get'  C:...\Post.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an Attribute like that. Attribute parameters are restricted to constant values.

Imo the better solution would be to provide a method on your class that implements this check and can be called through some business logic validation interface of your liking.

Comment: Totally disagree. You can't use a validation attribute specifically as it's written above, that's correct. However the problem that he's trying to solve is addressed perfectly using validation attributes. You're right, I believe, in that it makes sense to roll the validation logic itself into a re-usable component, you can then leverage that component within a validation attribute and simply plug it into the the rest of the dataannotations and model binding machinery.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, you can do what you're trying to do, just not the way you're currently doing it. (Incidentally, I just noticed that this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848684/compare-dates-dataannotations-validation-asp-net-mvc) has been answered very well already so I thought I'd at least drop a quick reference to it.)

Based on the link above...

1. You'll need to write a custom validator (which you've already done)
2. You'll need to decorate your model at the *class* level, not the property level
3. You won't be using the properties themselves as parameters - instead you'll simply reference them as strings to be looked up via reflection

`[Validate2Date(BeginDate, EndDate, ...`

becomes

`[Validate2Date(StartDate = "BeginDate", EndDate = "EndDate", ...`

You'll then override IsValid() and reflect over the the necessary properties to perform the comparison. [From the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848684/compare-dates-dataannotations-validation-asp-net-mvc)

```
.... 
        var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value);
        object originalValue = properties.Find(OriginalProperty, true /* ignoreCase */).GetValue(value);
        object confirmValue = properties.Find(ConfirmProperty, true /* ignoreCase */).GetValue(value);
        return Object.Equals(originalValue, confirmValue);
....
```