# .NET MVC Custom Date Validator

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

I'll be tackling writing a custom date validation class tomorrow for a meeting app i'm working on at work that will validate if a given start or end date is A) less than the current date, or B) the start date is greater than the end date of the meeting (or vice versa).

I think this is probably a fairly common requirement. Can anyone point me in the direction of a blog post that might help me out in tackling this problem?

I'm using .net 3.5 so i can't use the new model validator api built into .NET 4. THe project i'm working on is MVC 2.

UPDATE: THe class i'm writing needs to extend the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace. In .NET 4 there is a IValidateObject interface that you can implement, that makes this sort of thing an absolute doddle, but sadly i can't use .Net 4. How do i go about doing the same thing in .Net 3.5?

Comment: I've just been working on it. Maybe it will help:
[CompareDatesValidator][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848684/compare-dates-dataannotations-validation-asp-net-mvc/8070779#8070779

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
public sealed class DateStartAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        DateTime dateStart = (DateTime)value;
        // Meeting must start in the future time.
        return (dateStart > DateTime.Now);
    }
}

public sealed class DateEndAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string DateStartProperty { get; set; }
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        // Get Value of the DateStart property
        string dateStartString = HttpContext.Current.Request[DateStartProperty];
        DateTime dateEnd = (DateTime)value;
        DateTime dateStart = DateTime.Parse(dateStartString);

        // Meeting start time must be before the end time
        return dateStart < dateEnd;
    }
}
```

and in your View Model:

```
[DateStart]
public DateTime StartDate{ get; set; }

[DateEnd(DateStartProperty="StartDate")]
public DateTime EndDate{ get; set; }
```

In your action, just check that `ModelState.IsValid`. That what you're after?

Comment: In this case how do i pick up the values for StartDate and EndDate from the model, since they are both user entered values?

Comment: Changed my answer. :) So StartDate checks with DateTime.Now. EndDate checks with StartDate which is user entered to make sure it's after the start date.

Comment: Why my dateStartString from current context is null?

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is older, but, this solution I found is much better.

The accepted solution in this post won't work if the object has a prefix when it is part of a viewmodel.

i.e. the lines

```
// Get Value of the DateStart property
string dateStartString = HttpContext.Current.Request[DateStartProperty];
```

A better solution can be found here:
[ASP .NET MVC 3 Validation using Custom DataAnnotation Attribute](https://web.archive.org/web/20150204084444/http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=182):

New `DateGreaterThan` attribute:

```
public sealed class DateGreaterThanAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private const string _defaultErrorMessage = "'{0}' must be greater than '{1}'";
    private string _basePropertyName;

    public DateGreaterThanAttribute(string basePropertyName) : base(_defaultErrorMessage)
    {
        _basePropertyName = basePropertyName;
    }

    //Override default FormatErrorMessage Method
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(_defaultErrorMessage, name, _basePropertyName);
    }

    //Override IsValid
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //Get PropertyInfo Object
        var basePropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_basePropertyName);

        //Get Value of the property
        var startDate = (DateTime)basePropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        var thisDate = (DateTime)value;

        //Actual comparision
        if (thisDate <= startDate)
        {
            var message = FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName);
            return new ValidationResult(message);
        }

        //Default return - This means there were no validation error
        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[Display(Name = "StartDate")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[Display(Name = "EndDate")]
[DateGreaterThanAttribute("StartDate")]
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Definitely a better solution!  +1 for the helpful link!

Comment: Here is the entry from the wayback machine.
https://web.archive.org/web/20150204084444/http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=182

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
public boolean MeetingIsValid( DateTime start, DateTime end )
{
      if( start < DateTime.Now || end < DateTime.Now )
          return false;

      return start > end || end < start;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, after reading you answer i realised i needed to provide my info. Of course the code that you have provided will validate a date, but it wasn't that part of the problem i was stuck on. I needed to know what interfaces to implement to extend the dataannotations namespace. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        
        return View("department1");
    }
    public ActionResult Savedata(Vmdepartment vm)
    {

        Hrcontext context = new Hrcontext();
        context.deptentity.Add(vm.dept);
        context.SaveChanges();

        return View("department1", vm);
    }
    public ActionResult Index1(Vmdepartment vm)
    {
        vm.liDepartment = new List<department>();
        
        return View("departmentview",vm);
    }

    public ActionResult search(Vmdepartment vm) {
        var n = vm.dept.name;
        vm.liDepartment = new List<department>();
        Hrcontext context = new Hrcontext();
        vm.liDepartment = context.deptentity.Where(a => a.name == n).ToList();
        return View("departmentview",vm);

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].

Answer (score -1):

```
public ActionResult Index(vmemployee vme)

    {

        emplyee emp = new emplyee();
        vme.cities = new List<city>();

        vme.countries = new List<country>();

        vme.departments = new List<department>();

        Hrcontext context = new Hrcontext();
        vme.countries = context.cntentity.ToList();
        vme.cities = context.cityentity.ToList();
        vme.departments = context.deptentity.ToList();

        return View("employeelist", vme);
    }

    public ActionResult Index1(vmemployee vm)
    {

        vm.liemp = new List<emplyee>();
        return View("Searchemployee", vm);

    }
    [submit(Name = "sav")]
    public ActionResult save(vmemployee vme)
    {
        vme.cities = new List<city>();
        vme.countries = new List<country>();
        vme.departments = new List<department>();



        Hrcontext context = new Hrcontext();
        vme.countries = context.cntentity.ToList();
        vme.cities = context.cityentity.ToList();
        vme.departments = context.deptentity.ToList();
        vme.emp.Imagefile.SaveAs(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\hrsestem\hrsestem\images\" + vme.emp.Imagefile.FileName);
        vme.emp.Imagepath= (@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\hrsestem\hrsestem\images\" + vme.emp.Imagefile.FileName);

        if (ModelState.IsValid == true)
        {
            context.empentity.Add(vme.emp);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View("employeelist", vme);
    }
```