# CustomAttribute that validates 2 fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes

So i have these 2 input fields Fromdate and ToDate,

In MVC I want to create a CustomAttribute to ensure Fromdate is before ToDate.

Is this possible? if so how? or what is the alternative?

Thanks

Comment: Can this help you? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301022/Creating-Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-MVC-3?msg=4281482#xx4281482xx

Comment: does it apply to more than one field?

Comment: As the beginning of the article says: `There are lots of validation attributes available in MVC 3 but sometimes we may require specific type of validation which is dependent on some other properties as well`. The example in question is `I come across a situation where I need validation on a set of checkboxes. Validation I need was simple that at least one checkbox from the set must be checked`, so he is applying to more than one field, yes. He is checking if at least one of 3 checkboxes is checked.

Comment: Possible of duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614076/net-mvc-custom-date-validator

Answer (score 1):

MVC FoolProof Validation is a great way to go about this. It operates on the server side with a reference and also propagates client side with a script include.

http://foolproof.codeplex.com/

Here is an example of an attribute in action:

```
public class EventViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [GreaterThan("Start")]
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

See the GreaterThan Attribute on the date. This would save you having to write it all yourself.

You can also nuGet it into your project: http://nuget.org/packages/foolproof

```
PM> Install-Package foolproof
```

I hope this helps.