# Compare two input fields in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have two properties in model class:

```
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

here,`StartDate` should be always less than `EndDate` 
is there any data annotation for this in asp.net mvc

Comment: No built in attribute but you could look at using [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/)'s `[LessThan]` attribute

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614076/net-mvc-custom-date-validator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the option to write your own custom attribute, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18577850/3451056).

Another option is to use [Foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) (available from Nuget).

```
public class EventViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [GreaterThan("Start")]
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: doesnt work with jQuery Date picker. it only works when input is changed but picker doesnt cause on input change event